# rails--losing data from save by using method in model file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a scheduling app for merchandisers. I have a class "Jobs," using the following schema:

```
create_table "jobs", force: true do |t| 
    t.string "job_num" 
    t.string "project" 
    t.string "store_num" 
    t.string "store_name" 
    t.string "address" 
    t.date "start_date" 
    t.date "end_date" 
    t.time "time" 
    t.integer "sched_hrs" 
    t.integer "manpower" 
    t.datetime "created_at" 
    t.datetime "updated_at" 
    t.boolean "sat", default: false 
    t.boolean "sun", default: false 
    t.string "timezone" 
end
```

Most jobs don't include Saturday or Sunday hours, so part of my method is designed to either include or skip those days. The rest is simply to create new table rows in another model called "Shifts" --jobs may span many days, and I need to create a new entry (without the store info) for each day the job spans. So here's my Jobs model:

```
  class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :agents
    has_many :shifts

    attr_reader :id, :start_date, :end_date, :sched_hrs, :manpower

    validates :job_num, presence: true
    validates :project, presence: true
    validates :store_num, presence: true
    validates :store_name, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
    validates :start_date, presence: true
    validates :end_date, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true 
    validates :sched_hrs, presence: true 
    validates :manpower, presence: true


    after_create :splay


    private

     def splay

        @now_date = Date.parse(@start_date)
        @end_dt = Date.parse(@end_date)
        @j_id = @id
        @j_sh = @sched_hrs
        @j_mp = @manpower

        while @now_date <= @end_dt do 

            if @now_date.saturday? == false && @now_date.sunday? == false
                Shift.create(job_id: @j_id, shift_date: @now_date, shift_hrs: @j_sh, shift_req_agents: @j_mp, shift_available_agents: 0 )
            end

            if @now_date.saturday? == true && self.sat == true
              Shift.create(job_id: @j_id, shift_date: @now_date, shift_hrs: @j_sh,            shift_req_agents: @j_mp, shift_available_agents: 0 )
            end 

            if @now_date.sunday? == true && self.sun == true
             Shift.create(job_id: j_id, shift_date: @now_date, shift_hrs: @j_sh, shift_req_agents: @j_mp, shift_available_agents: 0 )
            end 

            @now_date += 1

            end

     end 
  end
```

After much trial and error I got the values to save to the Shifts table. But when I check the table row in Jobs, any parameters I passed to the method are not saved, and this results in NoMethod forNilClass errors. And because I'm using the :id from the Job class, it's making my Job table rows un-findable (no :id).

What I am I doing wrong here? Should this code be somewhere else - e.g. in a helper file or in the Controller? I'm confused.

Comment: You should post the full error message, and a few lines of the stack trace, or at least state which line throws the error.

Comment: So are you still having problems? Are you asking for advice on where the code should be stored, not what is wrong with the code?

Comment: How about allowing the "Job" to save and generate the Show view, then adding a button to the Show view that triggers a method to feed the "Shift" table the relevant data?

Comment: I'm not sure what question to ask, actually. The code, when I had it working (before messing it all up) sent data to the "Shifts" table--that worked fine. But any field I accessed to do so was somehow omitted from the submit from the "Job" form--all those fields in the db are showing nil (which is throwing NoMethod errors in the Show and index views for Job). Not only did those instance values not save, but the entire columns were being wiped from the Jobs table (including previously stored rows).  I need to feed relevant data to the Shift table while also successfully saving the Job data.

Comment: So I guess I'm asking both questions--should this be in the model, the controller, or a helper, and what am I doing that's erasing these particular column entries?

Comment: using self.foo (Job parameter) I was able to get the functionality...I think. I have to clear the dbs because the id numbers are off. The job_id is consistent from shift to shift (that's correct) but it's too high, like a bunch of nil rows are still left in the db after I destroyed all the records yesterday. Hmm. Oh, well, thanks for taking time to ponder my problem!! Floundering in the dark as I am, I'm sure more questions will come up.

Answer (score 0):

As a start to solving your problem, your "`Sunday`" conditional code is referencing `j_id`:

```
if @now_date.sunday? == true && self.sun == true
  Shift.create(job_id: j_id, shift_date: @now_date, shift_hrs: @j_sh, shift_req_agents: @j_mp, shift_available_agents: 0 )
end
```

You have only defined `@j_id` instead of `j_id`, so `j_id` is probably `nil`.

You can also take advantage of your `has_many` association by removing `job_id: @j_id`:

```
  @job = Job.find(@id)
  @job.shifts << Shift.create(shift_date: @now_date, shift_hrs: @j_sh, shift_req_agents: @j_mp, shift_available_agents: 0 )
```

Typically, you can create the associated `Shift` records while processing `form` input in a controller action.  That is, if you are actually obtaining this data through a controller action.

Also, you can cut down on a little bit of your logic.  For example:

```
  if @now_date.saturday? == true && self.sat == true
```

can be reduced to:

```
  if @now_date.saturday? && self.sat
```

since both `.saturday?` and `.sat` return booleans.

Comment: You're right, sealocal, and looking at it now it's a mess up there, I didn't completely roll back my code from another incarnation so there are all sorts of inconsistent variables, and as is probably obvious I'm hazy on the logic in general. Just trying to find the right combination/tactics/syntax to save the Job table row, and save the Shift table rows (with or without weekend days).  Might have helped if I had one consistent variable scheme. Apologize for not checking better. As to the error messages, they were most often NoMethod for nil.NilClass.  Running out of characters, still thinkin'.

Comment: Good point about the refactoring. I actually expanded that stuff earlier because I was having trouble getting the code to run (I was using the wrong variable forms, I think) and basically grasping at straws, trying everything I could think of. Now that it's run I feel more comfortable refactoring.

Comment: No problem.  Too bad I couldn't hit the nail on the head for you, but seems like you're getting it figured out.  Good luck!